# sending reminder mail when specific no. of days are left Which is manger by the Query SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, email, logic, scheduled-tasks, reminders

i want to send the Email on Certification expiry when **21,14,7,3,2,1** days are left by a **scheduler** which picks the data by the Query
 . 
i am using the **ExpiryNotification** bit col.as a flag(as previous it used to sent on 30 days only)

the data in the Query is picked from scheduler.now if i have to do changes in the **Query to implement this logic i will need to change the col from bit to int and  check the Notification col.but what if the Scheduler does not run when 21 days are left for some odd reason then what will happen**.is there any other way to implement this Logic by **sql server** ?

it will make the ExpiryNotification col value to **1** when the mail is send

exisitng Query (checking only 30 days)

```
   Select * from wsm_certification 
where
 (DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), wsm_Certification.RenewalDate) = 30 
and  wsm_Certification.ExpiryNotification = 0)
```

Comment: you could make ExpiryNotification to int and check value i.e 30days 1 flag,21days 2 flag,14 days 3 flag

Comment: but what if the Scheduker does not run when the 21 days are left ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this

```
(DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), wsm_Certification.RenewalDate) = 21 OR (DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), wsm_Certification.RenewalDate) = 14
```

Answer (score 1):

Use in operator to check multi values 
Eg:

Select * from wsm_certification 
where
 (DATEDIFF(d, GETDATE(), wsm_Certification.RenewalDate) in (21,14,7,3,2,1)
and  wsm_Certification.ExpiryNotification = 0)